# I am trying to get a simple jqplot example going but it will not display, why not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqplot

Here is the entire contents of the file:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>jqPlot Examples</title>

    <!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jqtouch-1_0_b/jqtouch/jquery.1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../javascript/jquery.jqplot.css" />
 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>jqPlot Examples</h1>

    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);
    </script>

div<br>
   <div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
div<br>


 </body>
</html>
<html>
```

Here is what I see in FF, chrome, IE:

jqPlot Examples

div

div

I am seeing no errors in my Apache error log. I know all the .js files are accessible from the html. Does anyone have an idea about why this might not be working?

Comment: I have sent this question to the jqplot msg board but it seems to take them a while to approve it. If I get any help from them I will will update this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got my answer from the [jqPlot message board](http://groups.google.com/group/jqplot-users/browse_thread/thread/7c8a711b7f95f1f4).

The `div` had to be before the call to `jqPlot`. I guess it makes sense but I just could not see it. My noob colors showing....

Comment: i tried to run with your code and its displaying like this 
http://jsfiddle.net/ejCC8/
in the head section i have included these 
<link class="include" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCoreDefault.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="syntaxhighlighter/styles/shThemejqPlot.min.css" />
After download from
https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/downloads/jquery.jqplot.1.0.8r1250.tar.bz2

Answer (score 5):

Replace your plotting script with this bit of code and see.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
 $(function() { var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1,2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]); })

</SCRIPT>
```

also check your .js files are in proper locations.

Answer (score 0):

use following link path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
```